# Ripple Drawable error even if i'm not using it anywhere

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I've not used any RippleDrawable instance or library in my code directly still whenever i compile my app it crashes and android monitor console states that Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering.

Here is the code of main activity.

```
package com.example.weatherapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static TextView placeTextView;
static TextView tempTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    placeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametextview);

    tempTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temptextview);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Double lng = location.getLongitude();
    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + String.valueOf(lat) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(lng) + "&appid=6cf59e488bc16d70d20fa680e619b60e");

}
```

}
 I think the error is in permission check. but dont know exactly what to do.
here is the default configuration of my app.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.weatherapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
}

Here is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nametextview"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/temptextview"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and stack trace

```
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16343: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16345: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16349: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-17 13:53:47.190 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 468: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-17 13:53:47.200 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-17 13:53:47.200 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 490: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-17 13:53:47.230 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
05-17 13:53:47.230 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16780: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
05-17 13:53:47.240 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
05-17 13:53:47.240 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 282: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
05-17 13:53:47.250 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
05-17 13:53:47.250 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 431: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
05-17 13:53:47.250 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
05-17 13:53:47.250 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 433: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
05-17 13:53:47.260 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
05-17 13:53:47.260 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 141 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
05-17 13:53:47.300 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418edc80)
05-17 13:53:49.770 17235-17235/com.example.weatherapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17235 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post your `activity_main.xml` and the stack trace also?

Comment: Added in the question